# Vowel Counter - Switch statement counting correctly

Tags: switch-statement, increment

Can someone please explain to me why this vowel counter is not correctly counting each vowel? I am confused by switch statements and very new to Java... This is an assignment and it is mandatory that I use a switch statement. I can make it work strictly using an if-else statement, but not with the switch statement... Thanks for looking :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userIn;
        
        System.out.println("Enter a word.");
        userIn = scan.nextLine();
        String str = userIn.toLowerCase(); 
        
        int countA = 0, countE = 0, countI = 0, countO = 0, countU = 0, nonVowel = 0, i = 0;
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        
        while(i < str.length())
        {
            
                if(str.charAt(i) == 'a') 
                    letter = 'A';
                else if(str.charAt(i) == 'e')
                    letter = 'E';
                else if(str.charAt(i) == 'i')
                    letter = 'I';
                else if(str.charAt(i) == 'o')
                    letter = 'O';
                else if(str.charAt(i) == 'u')
                    letter = 'U';
            
            switch(letter)
            {
                case 'A':
                    countA++;
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    countE++;
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    countI++;
                    break;
                case 'O':
                    countO++;
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    countU++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        i++;
    }
     System.out.println("This word contains: ");
     System.out.println("A's :" + countA);
     System.out.println("E's :" + countE);
     System.out.println("I's :" + countI);
     System.out.println("O's :" + countO);
     System.out.println("U's :" + countU);
     System.out.println("Non-vowel characters:" + (str.length() - (countA + countE + countI + countO+ countU)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How about "switch (str.charAt(i))" for a start?

Comment: @mpez that worked as long as I delete the extraneous if-else section! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Thanks @mpez0! I don't need the if-else statements at all. This worked...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelCount
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userIn;
        
        System.out.println("Enter a word.");
        userIn = scan.nextLine();
        String str = userIn.toLowerCase(); 
        
        int countA = 0, countE = 0, countI = 0, countO = 0, countU = 0, nonVowel = 0, i = 0;
        char letter = str.charAt(i);
        
        while(i < str.length())
        {
            
            switch(str.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'a':
                    countA++;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    countE++;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    countI++;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    countO++;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    countU++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        i++;
    }
     System.out.println("This word contains: ");
     System.out.println("A's :" + countA);
     System.out.println("E's :" + countE);
     System.out.println("I's :" + countI);
     System.out.println("O's :" + countO);
     System.out.println("U's :" + countU);
     System.out.println("Non-vowel characters:" + (str.length() - (countA + countE + countI + countO+ countU)));
    }
}
```